# How do I get the source code of various functions used in python library ta-lib?

Tags: python, finance

I want to cross-verify the functions used in the module and also want a brief understanding on how they are implemented.

The library can be found here-https://github.com/mrjbq7/ta-lib

I have checked in my Python lib and all the functions are given in .pyd format so don't know how to access them?

Comment: The link you give is for the Python wrapper, don't expect anything interesting going on there. You should probably check [the sources](http://sourceforge.net/p/ta-lib/code/HEAD/tree/) of the [actual TALIB](http://ta-lib.org/).

Comment: Thanks.Got the difference ,I tried finding but could you exactly point where i should look for the functions of technical indicators

Answer (score 1):

In short: You can't like this.

Why? .pyd are python "extension" modules that are written in C or C++. Apparenty for you lib, the code is written in C and then wrapped to python using [Cython](http://cython.org/) (the .pyx files). So if you you want to have a look at source code look at the C source code in the GitHub [repo](https://github.com/mrjbq7/ta-lib) (if you understand C of course).